# Xboard 4.9 installation

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, chess

I have been trying to install XBoard4.9.1, but I have run into two problems. I have versiom 16 of Ubuntu.

1) I am trying to do it using the *Ubuntu Sofware*, but it only installs only version 4.8 of Xboard and I can't connect it to ICS or FICS.

2) I downloaded the file Xboard'4.9.1.tar.gz, but I couldn't install it. I have never installed a program from a file.

I want install this program and connnected it to FICS (freechess.com.). How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to install XBoard from source code.

It is [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=Xboard) in Ubuntu repositories.
So the easiest way is to get 4.9.1 from 18.04 LTS and install package manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xboard/xboard_4.9.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./xboard_4.9.1-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you were of great help. I managed to install it, but had to install version 1386.db.

Now, my problem is that I can't connect to freechess.org. There is no menu to connect to. Only through command lines that I still don't understand.

Comment: I do not play chess, but what is interesting - the ICS menu item is disabled even on latest 20.04 LTS. So you have to use terminal command `xboard -ics -icsserver freechess.org` and then use some syntax which I do not know. For details see [`man xboard`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man6/xboard.6.html).

Comment: Thank you. This really worked for me!